# How to delete Object from deep javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to delete object from my array posted below but nothing works. If I delete the properties it just goes to undefined. I have a recursive function that returns to me the right object. I wish to delete the second object and his children.

```
var data = {
        parameters: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: "First",
                value: "1",
                children: []
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Second",
                value: "2",
                children: [
                            {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "Third",
                        value: "3",
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        index: 3
    }
```

Comment: use splice for that

Comment: Are you aware of the `delete` operator in JS? (not to be used on arrays) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: @tmslnz OP is already using `delete` operator. That is the why value becomes `undefined`

Comment: It may very well be if he's deleting from an array, but there's no mention of actually having tried `delete` in the post.

Comment: I tried with delete. I can use delete only on properties. Object is still there...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

> The **`splice()`** method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```
data.parameters.splice(1, 1)
//              index //  \\ length
```

Comment: I would rather suggest you to mark duplicate. We should not answer obvious duplicate.